# Cannot render conditional class in alpine js after fetching data in livewire

Tags: laravel, render, server-side-rendering, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

[image]

can someone help me with this problem i am trying to put conditional classes depending on the value given after rendering the data when i get to another paginate the conditional class in alpine js does not rendering it will be the same

```
 <td  class="py-4 px-6 text-center w-48">
                        <span x-data ="{roles: '{{ $user->account_status }}'}" :class="{ 'bg-slate-300 text-black': roles == 'LOCKED', 'bg-blue-300 text-blue-800': roles == 'OPEN'}" class=" text-sm font-medium mr-2 px-2.5 py-0.5 rounded-full dark:bg-blue-200 dark:text-blue-800"> {{ $user->account_status }}</span>
                    </td>
```

heres my code

cannot render conditional classes after server side rendering in livewire

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Alpine.js to render conditional classes

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#conditional-classes

```
@class=([
    'bg-blue-300 text-blue-800' => $user->account_status === 'OPEN',
    'bg-slate-300 text-black' => $user->account_status === 'LOCKED',
])
```

You should use Alpine to react on client side (tabs, clicks, switches, etc)